# Recursive sum function in bash

Tags: bash, recursion

I have a problem with writing it in bash... I know how it works in C++, but I have trouble implementing it in bash. Here's what I got:

```
sum() 
{
    let minusOne=$1-1
    let result=sum $minusOne +$1

}
```

Comment: Can you post the `C++` version of `sum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an exit condition. In bash, `$((...))` is arithmetic expansion, and `$(...)` is command substitution (see the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)).

```
sum() {
    if (( $1 == 1 )); then
        echo 1
        return
    fi
    local minusOne=$(( $1 - 1 ))
    echo $(( $1 + $(sum $minusOne) ))
}
```

A non-recursive way to write a sum function:

```
sum() {
  set -- $(seq 1 $1)
  local IFS=+
  echo "$*" | bc
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One question though, how do I get this value to a variable? Like let var = $(( $1 + $(sum $minusEna) )?? It gives an error(operand expected)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will give you a sum of numbers provided as arguments. The following prints "10":

```
#!/bin/bash

sum() {
    local total=0
    for number in "$@"; do
        (( total += number ))
    done

    echo $total
}

sum 1 2 3 4
```